# Is it SAFELY possible to use a str(BlobKey) as datastore id?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

Task: implement global, cross entity group blob sharing.

I need an ancestor group with either BlobInfo or a string-representation of the BlobKey as parent of the BlobReference objects to have strong consistency. So I construct a virtual ancestor group with the blob-key as parent of the referencing DB-object ...

```
br = BlobReferenece(id=some_id, parent = ndb.Key("MyBlobKey",str(blob))) 
br.put()
```

This works in SDK so far, but I am concerned that this is is way off the documeted paths of appengine.

My previous attempts failed to convert a blob-key to a db-key using ndb.Key.from_old_key(blobinfo.key()). It seems there is no legal way to get a "db/ndb" reference to the BlobInfo table (because The BlobInfo class provides a **db.Model-like interface**). Am I missing something here?

Comment: As long as the string'd blobinfo key is a valid photo is why would it be invalid?

Comment: However its not clear why you are doing this.  You need more than one child entity to make it worth while, as any entity we with no parent is by definition in its own entity group

Comment: n-times BlobReference are the child entities of the parent. The query to determine how many BlobReferences link to a single blob is necessary to delete the blob after it is no longer in use, or the last ref is deleted [query = BlobReference.query(ancestor=self.key.parent())]

Comment: ad comment 1: Using the string representation of a blobkey as id of a parent (without going trough normal DB-keys) is quite an odd approach, but the only one that allows this query without eventual consistency problems.

Comment: Agreed,, you hadn't said how many entities sharing the ancestor in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your question is asking whether you can create some kind of "virtual ancestor group" by specifying a parent that doesn't exist.  This is legitimate, it's mentioned in the docs that the parent doesn't actually need to exist.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Python_Ancestor_paths

Alternatively, if your list of BlobReferences will be limited, it would probably be easier and less expensive to just store a list of them inside one entity.  You an make the Key of that container entity the same as the BlobKey.  Then fetching that entity by key and modifying it will let you work without eventual consistency problems.  It'll also be cheaper than querying and modifying indexed entities.

Comment: I know that virtual ancestor groups are possible, but I do not know if there are any consequences of using blobkeys as key-ids, probably there are none. Storing them in a list of model does not allow subclassing the model to attach some useful properties to the referencing entity. I cannot really limit the references, some blobs will probably have 1000, others only one, if you share blobs globally. In any case you could duplicate the blob (thats hard) and create a new referencing group.

Answer (score 0):

You sound confused by the various uses of the word "key" in different parts of the API.  A blob key has nothing in common with an entity key.  The good news is that str() of a BlobKey instance is a sane base64-encoded string that should be fine to use as the ID portion of a Key object.  And you can go from that ID string to a BlobKey instance using the BlobKey constructor.

Comment: The slick thing on this approach is that blobkey = self.key.parent().id(). But, I also found out that fetching keys only from BlobInfo.all().fetch(3, keys_only=True) retrieves the db-keys(!) and ndb.Key.from_old_key(blobs[0]) works. This is an inconsistent API.
This way you could probably delete __BlobInfo__ instances.